# Make a textbox visible and other css changes on ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function getSearchClients() {
    console.log('Inside searchClient');
    $('#progressbar').show();
    var searchClientPhone = document.getElementById('searchClientCellPhoneNo').value;
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        data: "searchClientPhone=" + searchClientPhone,
        url: "searchClientCellPhoneNo",
        success: function(result){
            $("#progressbar").hide();
            $("#example td").each( function() {
                 var thisCell = $(this);
                 var cellValue = parseInt(thisCell.text());

                 if (!isNaN(cellValue) && (cellValue >= document.getElementById("selectedClientRewardPoints").value)) {
                     thisCell.css("background-color","#FF0000");
                  }
              }
             );

            $("#selectedClientName").show();
            $("#selectedClientRewardPoints").show();
            window.location.reload(true);

        }
    }); 
}
```

The textboxes do not become visible in the ajax success, though I have verified control goes to the success block.

Comment: It is unclear what information you want.  What help would you like?

Comment: Can you please include html...

Comment: You are reloading page on success, and that is why you can't see your DOM changes.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I have removed window.location.reload()  But, the issue I am facing now is that the text box value is now getting a new value after the ajax call, which I can verify using console.log(result) where the result is the value returned by ajax call. How can I show new updated value in the text box? $("#selectedClientName").show(); $("#selectedClientRewardPoints").show();

Comment: Can you post an example of the `result` object? What property do you want in in the textbox, and what is the `id` of the textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @JimmyBoh for the pointers, this is how I fixed the issue :

1) Used struts2-json library. In struts.xml, added below:

```
<package name="json" extends="json-default">
   <action name="searchClientCellPhoneNo"    class="com.intracircle.action.RedeemAction" method="searchClientCellPhoneNo">
     <result type="json">
        <param name="root">jsonData</param>
     </result>
   </action>
</package>
```

2) In the action class, added a jsonData Map as follows :

```
private Map<String,Object> jsonData = new HashMap<String,Object>();
```

Added getters and setters for jsonData

```
public Map<String,Object> getJsonData() {
    return jsonData;
}

public void setJsonData(Map<String,Object> jsonData) {
    this.jsonData = jsonData;
}
```

In the action method, added data to be returned to jsp to the jsonData Map as follows :

```
public String searchClientCellPhoneNo() {
    clientList = userdao.getClientsList(searchClientPhone);
    if(clientList !=  null && clientList.size() > 0) {
        selectedClientName = clientList.get(0).getProfileName();
        jsonData.put("selectedClientName",selectedClientName);
        int storeId = ((Stores)SecurityUtils.getSubject().getSession().getAttribute(SESSION_CONSTANTS.SESSION_STORE)).getStoreId();
        selectedClientRewardPoints = redeemDao.getCountRewardPointsForClientForStore(storeId, clientList.get(0).getId());
        jsonData.put("selectedClientRewardPoints", selectedClientRewardPoints);
    }
    viewRedeemScheme();
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

3) In the jsp ajax method, did the following changes : Make sure, you add dataType:'json' and if you want to print the ajax result using alter, stringify it.

```
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        data: "searchClientPhone=" + searchClientPhone,
        url: "searchClientCellPhoneNo",
        dataType: 'json',
        headers : {
            Accept : "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
            "Content-Type" : "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        },
        success: function(result){

        alert("result: " + JSON.stringify(result));
        console.log("Result " + result);

            $("#selectedClientName").val(result.selectedClientName);
    $("#selectedClientRewardPoints").val(result.selectedClientRewardPoints);
            $("#progressbar").hide();
            $("#example td").each( function() {
                 var thisCell = $(this);
                 var cellValue = parseInt(thisCell.text());

                 if (!isNaN(cellValue) && (cellValue >= document.getElementById("selectedClientRewardPoints").value)) {
                     thisCell.css("background-color","#FF0000");
                  }
              }
             );

            $("#selectedClientName").show();
            $("#selectedClientNameLabel").show();
            $("#selectedClientRewardPointsLabel").show();
            $("#selectedClientRewardPoints").show();

        }
    });
```

Thanks everyone for the help, especially @JimmyBoh.

Comment: I'm glad to see you got it working, but there are still a few issues with your code I'd like to point out. Anytime that you use `parseInt()` it must be called with 2 paramters, the first is the string/number and the second is the radix (typically 10). [See the MDN docs for more details.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) Also, `isNaN` also works with strings, so you should move that check to before your `parseInt` call. I'll update the answer so it has the appropriate usages.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because of `window.location.reload(true)`, why do you think to reload the page again!!

As per my understand, when the page is reloaded for a second time, the search input parameter becomes `null/empty`, so in this snippet `var cellValue = parseInt(thisCell.text());` `cellValue` is null/undefined.

Because of this, the following two lines do not function as expected

```
 $("#selectedClientName").show();
 $("#selectedClientRewardPoints").show();
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, the reason for doing reload was - ajax call returns me an updated value for the textboxes,  example this  is returned as a part of the ajax result : input type="text" name="selectedClientName" value="Client5678" readonly="readonly" id="selectedClientName"/>

Comment: So, if I don't do windows.location.reload, the textbox shows up as empty and not refreshed with the results returned by ajax call. How can that be fixed?

Comment: Doing a page reload for an ajax call (9 times out of 10) is counter productive to the goal of ajax. What kind of data are you expecting back from the ajax  call? JSON? XML? Plain Text?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your status like :

```
$("#progressbar").hide();
$("#selectedClientName").show();
$("#selectedClientRewardPoints").show();
```

you should store a boolean in the user localstore or a cookie (on ajax success). Then on the page just have a document ready:

```
$(document).ready({

if(localstorage/cookie) { / check the status of your cookie or localstorage

    $("#progressbar").hide();
    $("#selectedClientName").show();
    $("#selectedClientRewardPoints").show();

    // clear the cookie or the localstorage
}
});
```

I hope this gives you an idea man...

Answer (score 0):

There were a few things wrong. Primarily you were reloading the page, which is probably the main issue.

Also you had a few small issues with your number parsing and validating. I have fixed it below.

```
function getSearchClients() {
    console.log('Inside searchClient');
    $('#progressbar').show();
    var searchClientPhone = $('#searchClientCellPhoneNo').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "searchClientPhone=" + searchClientPhone,
        url: "searchClientCellPhoneNo",
        success: function (results) {
            $("#progressbar").hide();
            $("#example td").each(function () {
                var thisCell = $(this);
                var cellText = thisCell.text();

                // This will update your textbox...
                $("#selectedClientName").val(result.clientName);

                // And this is an example of updating based on an array of data.
                result.transactions.forEach(function(result){
                    // Create a list item and append it to the list.
                    $('<li></li>').text(result).appendTo('#resultList');
                });

                // If the cell text is a number... 
                if (!isNaN(cellText)) {

                    // Parse the text to a base 10 integer...
                    var cellValue = parseInt(thisCell.text(), 10);

                    if (cellValue >= $("#selectedClientRewardPoints").val()) {
                        thisCell.css("background-color", "#FF0000");
                    }
                }
            });

            $("#selectedClientName").show();
            $("#selectedClientRewardPoints").show();
            // Do not reload the page.
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. But, the issue I am facing now is that the text box value is now getting a new value after the ajax call, which I can verify using console.log(result) where the result is the value returned by ajax call. How can I show new updated value in the text box? $("#selectedClientName").show();
$("#selectedClientRewardPoints").show();

Comment: What is the `results` object?

Comment: Haha, no I mean can you post an example? Is it a javascript object or a string of HTML markup?

Comment: Extremely sorry, I didn't get you then. Its a HUGE html markup, which is the updated HTML for my page, with the textbox values now updated from the struts action. For example, now the textbox is returned in the result object as this : <input type="text" name="selectedClientName" value="Client5678" readonly="readonly" id="selectedClientName"/></td> with the value updated but on the page, its not updated. Guess, I should use find()

Comment: No, you shouldn't be returning HTML at all, at least not when using AJAX. The whole point of AJAX is to send and receive the least amount of info possible, so all you have to do is update one _element_, not the whole page. You really should watch some videos on jQuery and AJAX before trying to attempt something like this, because there are many ways that you can handle this type of interaction, more than can be explained through a SO answer.

Comment: Now, I understand that it returns HTML. My recommendation (without knowing the application goal) is to change that `POST` response to a 'GET' request that returns an array of client cell phone numbers (`POST` is meant for creating things). If you have it just return the data then you can insert those values into the elements as needed using `.append()`, `.appendTo()`, and `.text()`. But you need to change change that request to return an array, that is crucial.

Comment: Also, check out [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287810/how-to-update-an-html-table-through-ajax-call) for another example.

Comment: Thanks @JimmyBoh. I went through the details of ajax. Watched couple of video tutorials. Now what I have done is, returned a json from the ajax call. But, the problem I am facing is the returned json contains [object, Object], no matter I verifiy using console or alert. And If I use parseJSON to parse the ajax result, it gives me unexpected token o syntax error. I am already using datatype="json" in the ajax call. Any pointers on this? Thanks in advance!