# javascript, ajax - Update an HTML page by API call via ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, debugging, dynamic, form-submit

## Similar Issue

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287810/how-to-update-an-html-table-through-ajax-call) is similar to what I wanted, but not a particular solution to what I am seeking.

## My Issue

I want the user to input `Genesis` `1` then click **submit**, and the html pushes a submit request to my `bible_api_pull.js` which launches an ajax call to update the `index.html` page with that chapters text asynchronously.

## Current State of the Project

My html page: [here](https://github.com/conradbm/web_development/blob/master/resume-webpage/bible_api/index.html)

My Ajax call on submit: [here](https://github.com/conradbm/web_development/blob/master/resume-webpage/bible_api/index.html)

The actual website: [here](http://bmconrad.webutu.com/bible_api/index.html)

And my end goal was to store this information into a database with `id`, `bookName`, `chapterNumber`, and `chapterText` based on what the user pulled. However, I can't even seem to get the API populating the page correctly.

## Other Resources

I got the main API call code from [the api information here](https://getbible.net/api).

## Edit: Reproducible Example

So I have a container holding 2 inputs, `#bookInput` and `#chapterInput`. On `submit` they are successfully getting read into my `bible_api_pull.js` file below. However, it is not populating. Things I've tried:

1. Alerts will not work inside of the submit function call.
2. Updating a new `div` in my html to see whats going on inside of that api call that isn't working, but nothing gets read.

I am wondering if it is something very subtle I am missing, or if this really is a logic error in my understanding of javascript/ajax.

```
<!-- index.html -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <form id="target" class="form-inline" action="" method="">
              <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInput">Book</label>
              <input id="bookInput" name="bookId" type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" placeholder="Search book ...">

              <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInput">Chapter</label>
              <input id="chapterInput" name="chapterId" type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" placeholder="Search chapter ...">


              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="">Submit</button>
              <img src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" id="loading-indicator" style="display:none;position:absolute;top:"+$(window).height()/2+"px;left:"+$(window).width()/2+"px;" />
        </form>

        <hr>

        <div id="scripture"> </div>
    </div>
</div>


// bible_api_pull.js
$('#target').submit(function(event){

    // Next up ... dynamically accept the users choice!!!! Each input has it's own ID now!
    $('#loading-indicator').show();

    // Load the data
    var book = $("#bookInput").val();
    var chapter= $("#chapterInput").val();
    //var keywordInput = $("#searchInput").val();
    var book_chapter = book+chapter;

    // Pass the data
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:'http://getbible.net/json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: 'p='+book_chapter+'&v=kjv',
        jsonp: 'getbible',
        success:function(json){

            // set text direction
            if (json.direction == 'RTL'){
                var direction = 'rtl';
            } else {
                var direction = 'ltr'; 
            }
            /********************************************/
            /* Formatting for verses being returned     */
            /********************************************/
            if (json.type == 'verse'){
                var output = '';
                    jQuery.each(json.book, function(index, value) {
                        output += '<center><b>'+value.book_name+' '+value.chapter_nr+'</b></center><br/><p class="'+direction+'">';
                        jQuery.each(value.chapter, function(index, value) {

                            output += '  <small class="ltr">' +value.verse_nr+ '</small>  ';
                            output += value.verse;
                            output += '<br/>';
                        });
                        output += '</p>';
                    });
                jQuery('#scripture').html(output);  // <---- this is the div id we update
            } 
            /********************************************/
            /* Formatting for chapters being returned   */
            /********************************************/
            else if (json.type == 'chapter'){
                var output = '<center><h3><b>'+json.book_name+' '+json.chapter_nr+'</b></h3></center><br/><p class="'+direction+'">';
                jQuery.each(json.chapter, function(index, value) {
                    if(value.verse.includes(keywordInput)){
                        output += '  <small class="ltr">' +value.verse_nr+ '</small>  ';
                        output += value.verse;
                        output += '<br/>';
                    }
                });
                output += '</p>';
                jQuery('#scripture').html(output);  // <---- this is the div id we update
            } 
            /********************************************/
            /* Formatting for books being returned      */
            /********************************************/
            else if (json.type == 'book'){
                var output = '';
                jQuery.each(json.book, function(index, value) {
                    output += '<center><h1><b>'+json.book_name+' '+value.chapter_nr+'</b></h1></center><br/><p class="'+direction+'">';
                    jQuery.each(value.chapter, function(index, value) {
                        output += '  <small class="ltr">' +value.verse_nr+ '</small>  ';
                        output += value.verse;
                        output += '<br/>';
                    });
                output += '</p>';
            });
            if(addTo){
                jQuery('#scripture').html(output);  // <---- this is the div id we update
            }
          }
         $('#loading-indicator').hide();
        },
        error:function(){
            jQuery('#scripture').html('<h2>No scripture was returned, please try again!</h2>'); // <---- this is the div id we update
         },
    });


    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Blake, could you post the relevant parts of your code in your post, instead of links to external issues?  Also, show what you've attempted.  One of the features of StackOverflow is its search feature, which enables users to find similar questions and answers even close to a decade ago.  External links don't always have the staying power we hope they do, the content changes, and it doesn't make the post as searchable.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @vol7ron great point. Let me update with the specific parts that are what I believe are causing some problems.

Comment: @Jaramanda I have updated with a small example from my code that isn't working as expected. It can easily be placed in `<script></script>` tags and run independently. Let me know if there is anything else I should be aware of that I am either not making clear or am poorly communicating, and I will edit my question further to make it beneficial to all readers, not only my problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

I didnt understand what was your issue?
But anyway this code is quite straight forward. 
I commented `if(value.verse.includes(keywordInput)){` because `var keywordInput = $("#searchInput").val();` variable was commented during declaration and it's working now. 
Check the response and let me know what exactly you wanted.

```js
 $('#target').submit(function(event){

    // Next up ... dynamically accept the users choice!!!! Each input has it's own ID now!
    //$('#loading-indicator').show();

    // Load the data
    var book = $("#bookInput").val();
    var chapter= $("#chapterInput").val();
    //var keywordInput = $("#searchInput").val();
    var book_chapter = book+chapter;

    // Pass the data
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:'http://getbible.net/json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: 'p='+book_chapter+'&v=kjv',
        jsonp: 'getbible',
        success:function(json){

            // set text direction
            if (json.direction == 'RTL'){
                var direction = 'rtl';
            } else {
                var direction = 'ltr'; 
            }
            /********************************************/
            /* Formatting for verses being returned     */
            /********************************************/
            if (json.type == 'verse'){
                var output = '';
                    jQuery.each(json.book, function(index, value) {
                        output += '<center><b>'+value.book_name+' '+value.chapter_nr+'</b></center><br/><p class="'+direction+'">';
                        jQuery.each(value.chapter, function(index, value) {

                            output += '  <small class="ltr">' +value.verse_nr+ '</small>  ';
                            output += value.verse;
                            output += '<br/>';
                        });
                        output += '</p>';
                    });
                jQuery('#scripture').html(output);  // <---- this is the div id we update
            } 
            /********************************************/
            /* Formatting for chapters being returned   */
            /********************************************/
            else if (json.type == 'chapter'){
                var output = '<center><h3><b>'+json.book_name+' '+json.chapter_nr+'</b></h3></center><br/><p class="'+direction+'">';
                jQuery.each(json.chapter, function(index, value) {
                    
                        output += '  <small class="ltr">' +value.verse_nr+ '</small>  ';
                        output += value.verse;
                        output += '<br/>';
                    
                });
                output += '</p>';
                jQuery('#scripture').html(output);  // <---- this is the div id we update
            } 
            /********************************************/
            /* Formatting for books being returned      */
            /********************************************/
            else if (json.type == 'book'){
                var output = '';
                jQuery.each(json.book, function(index, value) {
                    output += '<center><h1><b>'+json.book_name+' '+value.chapter_nr+'</b></h1></center><br/><p class="'+direction+'">';
                    jQuery.each(value.chapter, function(index, value) {
                        output += '  <small class="ltr">' +value.verse_nr+ '</small>  ';
                        output += value.verse;
                        output += '<br/>';
                    });
                output += '</p>';
            });
            if(addTo){
                jQuery('#scripture').html(output);  // <---- this is the div id we update
            }
          }
         $('#loading-indicator').hide();
        },
        error:function(){
            jQuery('#scripture').html('<h2>No scripture was returned, please try again!</h2>'); // <---- this is the div id we update
         },
    });


    event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <form id="target" class="form-inline" action="" method="">
              <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInput">Book</label>
              <input id="bookInput" name="bookId" type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" placeholder="Search book ...">

              <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInput">Chapter</label>
              <input id="chapterInput" name="chapterId" type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" placeholder="Search chapter ...">


              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="">Submit</button>
              
        </form>

        <hr>

        <div id="scripture"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope you understand :)

Comment: You have no idea how much I love you. That one line must have been breaking because I deleted that searchbox. Thank you!!!

Comment: LOL, i understand that pain. Glad i could help you :)